IRS agent visits villain's lair
This is a short story probably from the early 1980s in Asimovs or Analog. An IRS agent (or equivalent) confronts a supervillain (Ming-the-Merciless-like) at his castle/lair, and effectively presents him with enough of a threat of imprisonment, etc., that the villain is cowed, in spite of the villain's superweaponry. As the story ends,

the supervillain has become an agent, and is confronting another supervillain (perhaps Vader-like?).


"The Examination of Ex-Emperor Ming" by Cyn Mason, Asimov's, July 1982. Internet Archive is giving me an error message at the moment, but this review is clear:

‘The Examination of Ex-Emperor Ming’, Cyn Mason (1982), is yet another piece of dated fluff. An agent of the Intragalactic Revenue Korps (why the “k”?) turns up at deposed emperor Ming’s palace with a demand for payment of back-taxes. Ming resists, is subsequently fined, and so bankrupted. But all is not lost as there is an organisation happy to employ someone with his experience and nature… Yes, it really is that corny.

P.S.  I suspect the K is there to make the acronym "irk" - as in "Ming was irked by the agent's presence."
Got the Archive to work.
The story begins:

There were deep bum marks on the road to the fortress. Many turrets
stood against the walls, lending ominous meaning to the scars. A lone
figure stood at the gates, knocking. "Halt, fool! Who dares disturb
the solitude of Ming the Merciless?” The echoes rolled over the hills,
precipitating a small landslide half a kilometer away.


"Not bad,”
commented the fool. "I see you have the 'Voice of Authority’ option
on your subterranean speakers. I’m here about the audit.”


Instantly
the turrets spat forth assorted rays, engulfing him in flames.
Ignoring them, the burning figure calmly walked to the castle gates
and kicked them. The turrets ceased firing as the gates fell inward. A
mob of robot gladiators rushed him as he stepped inside. The man
grabbed one, ignoring the others as they variously beat, slashed, and
fired at him, and politely requested, "Will you please tell Mr. Ming
that Special Agent David Klarven from the Intragalactic Revenue Korps
is here?”

and ends with:

"That’s more than five times the tax I paid as Emperor of Mongo!
You’ve bankrupted me! ’They’ll be calling me Ming the Penniless!” he
shrieked, his voice cracking. "How do you expect me to live? Do you
think the Galaxy is full of job openings for cruel despots? Guards!
Guards!” ’The robots assembled at the door. "I order you to destroy
this intruder if it means leveling the castle!”


One gladiator stepped
ahead of the rest. "We cannot obey you,” it stated. "Why?” "We no
longer belong to you,” it answered, and left. '"That’s correct,”
Klarven said. "l.R.K. Central just placed a tax levy on each of your
accounts, and filed a tax lien on this place.” "What can I do?” gasped
Ming. "I'm ruined.” His face was gray, the pupils dilated. "Well, wait
a minute. Possibly I have a proposition for you.”


There were deep burn
marks on the road to the fortress. Many peculiar turrets stood against
the walls, lending ominous meaning to the scars. A lone figure stood
at the gates, knocking. A challenge shook the hills. "Who dares
approach?” "Mr. Vader? Special Agent Ming, from the Intragalactic
Revenue Korps. I’m here about the audit.”

In answer to the question asked in the comments about why Ming is subject to taxation, it seems to be implied that the Intragalactic authority encompasses Mongo and many other polities.

Korps is the German word, sci-fi authors like to use words that sounds foreign; and given the perception of Germany after WW2 it makes it sound authoritarian.

… Surely, as the former Emperor, any taxes collected during his reign were collected on behalf of Ming.  Was he supposed to owe them to himself?  Retroactively applying taxes to that period seems like both an Ex Post Facto scenario, and also a dangerous precedent (i.e. if the Government then decided that Charities paid half-tax instead of being tax-free, then back-taxing Ming could be used to support back-taxing charities too…)

I don't quite recall the scenario, but an ex-Emperor may owe substantial taxes to the current Empire, all accumulated post-reign.

@coredump: The two are not exclusive. Korps may have been used because German-sounding felt better AND because IRK is such a wonderful acronym.

@Chronocidal - If he was a US citizen, or doing business on US soil, the IRS doesn't care much what his pretensions were (or even how legal they were). It just wants is due.

@T.E.D. I mean, "charging someone tax for their mother having been a citizen of your country, even if they were born elsewhere and have never visited" is pretty darn pretentious too.  There is, internationally, a lot dispute of what the IRS falsely and imperialistically believe they are "due".  But that's probably outside the scope of this question.
